# How long does AWS IAM's principle identifiers can be set and how to do if it exceeds the limitation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, policy

If set an AWS IAM policy document as

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "codeartifact:CreateRepository",
    ]
    resources = [
      "${aws_codeartifact_domain.example.arn}",
    ]
    principals {
      identifiers = [
        "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/xxx-1",
        "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/xxx-2",
        "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/xxx-3",
        "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/xxx-4",
        # ... until 100 or 1000 or 10000 ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How many identifiers can be set here? if it exceeds the limitation, how to do?

Another question, is it possible to use `*` after `arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/`?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? For sure there must be a better way.

Comment: @Marcin I want to set many different identifier for one AWS account in the block. Just worry it will reach the limitation(if exists) one day.

Comment: I mean, Why do you need 10000 roles in one policies?

Comment: @Marcin It's an imagine. In fact we don't need 10000 roles. So is it possible to create multiple policies for different groups(but with the same actions and resources)? That maybe doesn't have the limitation problem.

Comment: What are you _actually_ wanting to achieve (rather than imagining)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know (and [the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-quotas.html) tells us) you can continue to add as many principals as you want, as long as your policy stays under the IAM Policy limit size, which varies depending on what you attach it to:

- User policy size cannot exceed 2,048 characters.
- Role policy size cannot exceed 10,240 characters.
- Group policy size cannot exceed 5,120 characters.

Unfortunately this means that the answer to your question is "it depends" on how much *other* stuff you have in your policy (i.e. resources and actions).

To get around this limit you'd have to split the principals in to multiple policies, and attach them. Then you need to worry about the number of policies that can be attached to an entity, and the number of policies you can have in an account (refer to the quota page linked above).

Comment: Thank you. I have a question. Is my case `managed policies` or `inline policies`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're code sample above is from (it's not JSON), but given it's creating a policy document I would assume it is a `managed` (technically a `customer managed policy`). Inline policies are defined in the resource they apply to (e.g. a user or role).

Comment: I'm using terraform to create the resource. Thank you for your answer.